# Calculating percentages in a table in SQL

Tags: sql, percentage

I currently have a table of figures, but want to convert this into percentages and can't work out  how to do this in SQL

My table looks like....

| Animal | Number | Feed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Dog | 7 | 76 |
| Cat | 12 | 98 |
| Parrot | 8 | 32 |
| Mouse | 2 | 53 |

And the output table that I'd like...

| Animal | Number % | Feed % |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Dog | 23.3 | 29.2 |
| Cat | 40 | 37.7 |
| Parrot | 26.6 | 12.7 |
| Mouse | 10 | 20.4 |

For example, the Dog Number % is 7 / (7+12+8+2) * 100

The code I'm using at the moment is...

```
SELECT Animal, 
Number / SUM(Number) * 100 AS 'Number %', 
Feed / SUM(Feed) * 100 AS 'Feed %' 
FROM Vets
```

This only produces the top line (Dog) and not for all the animals.

Appreciate any help!

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (I'd have expected an error.)

Answer (score 0):

in case your rdbms does not support the sum windowing function you could do a subquery to mimic it

```
   SELECT
animal,
number / (select sum(number) from vets)* 100,
feed / (select sum(feed) from vets)* 100
FROM vets
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this if you are using `mysql` :

```
SELECT v.Animal, Round(v.Number/SumNumber*100,1) as 'Number %', Round(v.Feed/SumFeed*100, 1) as 'Feed %'
FROM Vets v
inner join (
  select Sum(Number) as SumNumber, Sum(Feed) as SumFeed
  from Vets vs
) as s on v.Animal <> '';
```

Answer (score 0):

SUM OVER works in SQL Server - [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/DpKztnpd)

```
SELECT animal,
       ROUND(number / SUM(number)over() * 100, 1) AS [Number%],
       ROUND(feed / SUM(feed)over() * 100, 1) AS [Feed%]
  FROM #vets
```